# How to iterate and process every heading in ORG file

Tags: elisp, org-mode

I want to iterate and check every heading in an ORG file, and see if it's a link to an image file or not. If it is, I need to do some processing on the heading.

```lisp
* no_image_heading  # should print nothing
* [[/path/to/img.png][description]] # should print the filename (in my test function)
```

My current code is:

```lisp
(defun my/org-img-link-p ()
  "Check if heading is a link to an image."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((context (org-element-context)))
    (and (eq (car context) 'link)
         (string= (org-element-property :type context) "file")
         (member (file-name-extension (org-element-property :path context))
                 '("jpg" "png")))))

(defun my/org-parse-img-heading ()
  "Parsing of headings"
  (interactive "r")
  (if (my/org-img-link-p)
      (message "%s" (org-element-property :path (org-element-context)))
    ;(do-something-else-with-heading)
    ))

(defun my/org-test-function ()
  (interactive)
  (org-map-entries 'my/org-parse-img-heading))
```

However, it never prints the file, even though `my/org-img-link-p` works if I have a cursor on the heading and I do `eval` `(my/org-img-link-p)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org-element-context`'s return value is dependent on where the cursor is. In the next examples `|` is were the cursor is placed.

- > * [[path/to/img.jpg][desc | ription]]

`eval (org-element-context)` returns

> (link (:type "fuzzy" :path "path/to/img.jpg" :format bracket :raw-link "path/to/img.jpg" :application nil :search-option nil ...))

- > | * [ [path/to/img.jpg][description]]

`eval (org-element-context)` returns

> (headline (:raw-value "[[path/to/img.jpg][description]]" :begin 18632 :end 18667 :pre-blank 0 :contents-begin nil :contents-end nil ...))

`org-map-entries` iterates over the headings with the cursor at the beginning (like example 2), so I don't have access to the `link` property. To solve this problem, I can move the cursor up to the beginning of the text or I can rewrite my function to analyse the text itself. I chose the latter.

```lisp
(defun mp/org-parse-img-heading ()
  "Expand the link to images in the heading for exporting to pdf"
  (interactive)
  ;; get the title of the heading
  (let ((heading (org-element-property :title (org-element-context))))
    ;; check if title is a link to a file
    (when (string-match "\\[\\[\\(.*\\)\\]\\[\\(.*\\)\\]\\]" heading)
      (let ((path (match-string 1 heading))
            (description (match-string 2 heading)))
        ;; check if link links to an image    
        (when (member (file-name-extension path) '("jpg" "png"))
          ;; edit the headline
          (org-edit-headline (format "%s\n[[%s]]" description path)))))))
```